# Accommodation with relatives on UK trip. Are they bearing cost of expenses?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, family, homestay

I am applying for a standard tourist visa to the UK from India. It is a holiday trip with my wife and 2 kids. We will be staying with my cousin and his family who is a British citizen for more than 30 years. So our accommodation and majority of food expenses are taken care of by them. I have the necessary letter and documents from my cousin indicating his willingness to host us and bear these expenses.

For the question in the visa application, "Will anyone be paying towards the cost of your visit" - should I answer YES?? Is my cousin also "paying" towards the cost by hosting us?

I thought NO as I will be paying for the tickets, visa expenses and also have proof of funds for costs incurred towards sightseeing,food, attractions and shopping. Please advise.

For my children's application, I had the question "Their relationship to you" for the person we are staying with. I put UNCLE but it was not one of the standard answer options for this question - is this OK?

Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: How long will you be staying with your cousin? He is paying for food expenses for 4 people - if you’re just staying a day or two this isn’t much, but if it’s longer the cost to him will be greater. It is also a cost of the trip that you’re not covering personally. I would estimate an amount per day for food and include that figure in the application. You can explain the approach in the further information section at the end.

Comment: @Traveller We are staying for 16 days. So should I answer YES to the question?  I assume 2 primary meals a day will be at my cousins while other food expenses while we  are out and about I will bear. Is this the amount you ask me to estimate and add to the cost of my trip? Would 3000 GBP for 4 people for 16 days be a reasonable estimate including flight tickets? No accommodation expenses.

Comment: @Vikki I can’t really answer on budget - it depends what you plan to do. Assuming flights are around £350pp means almost 50% of your budget on travel. It should be easy to do some research on attraction entrance fees, travel costs while in the U.K. etc to enable you to compile a realistic budget

Comment: @Traveller I have done the research on the daily costs based on what we want to do in London and have a pretty realistic budget. My query was more on whether I should answer as YES to this question on the visa application form as my cousin is clearly bearing some expenses but is happy to do so. Would saying YES mean he is a sponsor for the trip? I am a little confused on what to put. Its more of a technicality on how the ECO would view this information.

Comment: If I give you £10 to help you paying your flight tickets, then "someone is paying towards the cost of your visit". "Paying towards" means paying some amount, not necessarily all of it.

Answer (score 1):

As you will be staying with your relative and he will bear a part of the cost, yes, you will have to answer yes on the question: "Will anyone be paying towards the cost of your visit".
You will be able to explain who and how much you expect they will spend for you on the form, either in an explanation on this question or in an other part of the form. 'Staying with relative and taking part of our meals there' should do.
Your cousin is not a sponsor to your trip, that would be if he pays part of the travel costs and out of your text I do not get the impression he will do so.

I think the proper UK English version for the relationship of your children with your host will be 'cousin' (second cousin once removed may be the more precise, but as cousin is a wide catch word, I think that alone should do, even when with the different generation 'uncle' seems a more natural way to address.) You can also say 'cousin of parent' if that fits.